# How to install openssl cryptographic library on Lubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, apt-get, luks, cryptography

I'm trying to build cryptsetup 1.6.8 (or 1.7.0) from source using the openssl libraries instead of `libgcrypt`.

```
./configure --with-crypto_backend=openssl
```

I did install libssl-dev but it still gives me this error:

```
configure: error: You need openssl library.
```

Have I to install some others libraries? I searched on the web and everywhere they refer to the openssl lib for ubuntu, debian ad `libssl-dev`

Answer (score 3):

> How to install openssl cryptographic library on Lubuntu

Use:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Also see [What is “openssl binaries” and “openssl development package”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/318775) on the Ubuntu Stack Exchange.

---

> ... they refer to the openssl lib for ubuntu, debian ad `libssl-dev`

Yep.

Comment: I did that but it does not resolve the issue...

Comment: @Raffaele - Well, I'm not sure... Your question was, *"How to install openssl cryptographic library on Lubuntu"*. Perhaps you should open another question.

Comment: you're right, I forgot to mention that I'm compiling cryptsetup and it tells me `configure: error: You need openssl library.` even after installing libssl-dev

Comment: Update: if you want to compile cryptsetup with openssl backend, be sure to install pkg-config in addition to libssl-dev.